# Android: detect if nearby device has certain app installed

Tags: android, detection

I am not sure if that is even possible. It might be possible if both devices have the same app installed but what I am curious about is totally different.

What I am curious about is if that would be possible to code any kind of app that will tell if a nearby device has for example Whatsapp, or Facebook or...etc installed.

Or maybe it will fall into privacy issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

First, you have no means of communicating with an arbitrary nearby device, unless there is some app on that device that specifically is requesting that sort of communications.

Second, even if there is some app on the nearby device that happens to be listening on some communications channel, it is unlikely to be exposing some sort of API over that channel that allows you to check to see what apps are installed. If an app does this, that app itself is riddled with privacy and security flaws.

Comment: yes yes that makes a lot of sense of course, however, there is these apps that give you info about the user in the other end, like this kind of second-hand sell apps, telling you that the user is located 3km away from you. But that might be a different GPS location thing I guess??.

Comment: @eddie: "there is these apps that give you info about the user in the other end" -- the other user is running the same app, and that app is uploading location information to some server. Or, the other user is running some other app, and that other app is uploading location information to its server, and the server share data via some API and license terms.